# Как "прибить" footer к самому низу сайта?

Tags: html, css

```css
header, footer, body, .video-conteiner {
    background-color: darkolivegreen
}

.navbar p {
    color: darkgray;
    padding-left: 15%;
}
    /*Стили панели навигации при наведении мышью*/
    .navbar p:hover {
        color: aliceblue;
    }
/* Простые селекторы*/
.video-container {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-top: 1%;
}

.navbar {
    color: darkgray;
    padding-left: 15%;
}

header {
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-top: 1.2%;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: medium;
    color: dimgrey;
}

aside {
    height: 100%; /* Высота в полный размер. Этот параметр можно убрать, если вы хотите выставлять высоту автоматически */
    width: 10%;
    position: absolute; /* Фиксированная позиция сайд-бара. Так он будет оставаться на месте при скроллинге */
    z-index: 1; /* Сайд-бар будет поверх остальных элементов */
    top: 0; /* Сайдбар будет в самой верхней части страницы */
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111; /* Черный цвет фона (задан в виде кода) */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Отключаем горизонтальную прокрутку */
    padding-top: 2%;
    font-size: large;
}

body {
    padding-left: 11%;
}
/* Стили футера */
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Высота footer */
    height: 30px;
    background: black;
    line-height: 66%;
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>LifeSpot</title>
    <!--Подключение стилей по относительному пути из внешнего файла-->
    <link href="../Static/CSS/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
</head>
<header>
    <!--Заголовок страницы-->
    <h1>LifeSpot - прямые трансляции с улиц</h1>
    <!--Параграф-->
    <p>Покажем, что происходит прямо сейчас</p>
</header>
<aside id="sidebar">
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="/"><p>Все трансляции</p></a>
        <a href="/"><p>О проекте</p></a>
    </div>
</aside>
<body>
    <div class="bordered">
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srlpC5tmhYs" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <h3 class="video-title">Нью-Йорк, Брайант Парк</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wCcMcaiRbhM" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <h3 class="video-title">Санкт-Петербург, Невский Проспект</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JplMzss6_YE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <h3 class="video-title">Лондон, автобусный маршрут</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<footer>
    <p>LifeSpot - все права защищены</p>
    <p>Связаться с нами: contact@lifespot.ru</p>
</footer>
```

Пишу учебный сайт, и в нем футер залазит на один из блоков, как мне "прибить" его в самый низ, чтобы он не мешал?

Comment: есть несколько [решений](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page), но я бы рекомендовал во всех случаях (если по учебному курсу это разрешено) пользоваться flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как "прибить" footer к самому низу сайта?

Начать нужно с наведения порядка в `html`... Потом прибраться в `css`...

Предложу вот такой вариант. Возможно он и устроит...

```css
header,
footer,
body,
.video-conteiner {
  background-color: darkolivegreen
}

body {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.navbar p {
  color: darkgray;
  padding-left: 15%;
}


/*Стили панели навигации при наведении мышью*/

.navbar p:hover {
  color: aliceblue;
}


/* Простые селекторы*/

.video-container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 1%;
}

.navbar {
  color: darkgray;
  padding-left: 15%;
}

header {
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 1.2%;
}

aside {
  height: 100%;
  /* Высота в полный размер. Этот параметр можно убрать, если вы хотите выставлять высоту автоматически */
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  /* Фиксированная позиция сайд-бара. Так он будет оставаться на месте при скроллинге */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Сайд-бар будет поверх остальных элементов */
  top: 0;
  /* Сайдбар будет в самой верхней части страницы */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  /* Черный цвет фона (задан в виде кода) */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Отключаем горизонтальную прокрутку */
  padding-top: 2%;
  font-size: large;
}

body {
  padding-left: 11%;
}


/* Стили футера */

footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Высота footer */
  /*height: 30px;*/
  background: black;
  line-height: 66%;
  margin-top: auto;
  font-size: medium;
  color: dimgrey;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>LifeSpot</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <!--Заголовок страницы-->
    <h1>LifeSpot - прямые трансляции с улиц</h1>
    <!--Параграф-->
    <p>Покажем, что происходит прямо сейчас</p>
  </header>
  <aside id="sidebar">
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="/">
        <p>Все трансляции</p>
      </a>
      <a href="/">
        <p>О проекте</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <div class="bordered">
    <div class="video-container">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/srlpC5tmhYs" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <h3 class="video-title">Нью-Йорк, Брайант Парк</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="video-container">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wCcMcaiRbhM" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <h3 class="video-title">Санкт-Петербург, Невский Проспект</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="video-container">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JplMzss6_YE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <h3 class="video-title">Лондон, автобусный маршрут</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>LifeSpot - все права защищены</p>
    <p>Связаться с нами: contact@lifespot.ru</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```